# Ajax wait till big image is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, preload

i need to load big imges step by step using Ajax. I want to fade out the last Image only when the next Image is fully loaded.

I have checked several Solutions in all actual Browsers but nothing seems to work.

So this is what i have now:

```
<div id="imgToShow">
    <img class="imgZoomClass" src="firstimage.jpg">
```

This Ajax Function loads onclick the actual Image (path) and also the next Image path:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "../ajax/getImages",
    cache: true,
    data: "instance_id=" + $("#instance_id").val() + "&daterange=" + activeRange + "&index=" + slideIndex + "&direction=next&resolution=" + $("#resolution").val(),
    success: function(json){
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

        if(data){
            $("#imgToShow").append('<img id="imgZoom" class="imgZoomClass" data-index="'+data.index+'" data-time="'+data.time+'" data-date="'+data.date+'" src="'+data.path+'">');
            $(".imgZoomClass:first").remove().fadeOut();
        }
    }
});
```

This loads the next Image path, append it to #imgToShow and remove the old Image BUT this is flickering in browser because the old Image is removed before or meanwhile next Image is loading.

For any help i will be very grateful

Answer (score 1):

Before loading you have to hide image,you need to give some fade in effect after load image

```
<div id="imgToShow">
    <img class="imgZoomClass" src="firstimage.jpg"  onload="fadeIn(this)" />
</div

// fade in effect function
window.fadeIn = function(obj) {
    $(obj).fadeIn(1000, function(){
        $("#imgToShow").find(".imgZoomClass").not($(obj)).remove();
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "../ajax/getImages",
    cache: true,
    data: "instance_id=" + $("#instance_id").val() + "&daterange=" + activeRange + "&index=" + slideIndex + "&direction=next&resolution=" + $("#resolution").val(),
    success: function(json){
    var data = jQuery.parseJSON(json);

        if(data){
            $("#imgToShow").append('<img id="imgZoom" onload="fadeIn(this)" style="display:none;" class="imgZoomClass" data-index="'+data.index+'" data-time="'+data.time+'" data-date="'+data.date+'" src="'+data.path+'">');
        }
    }
});
```

in your CSS

```
#imgToShow
{
    position: relative;
    width: 400px; // set custom width as you need
    height: 400px; // set custom height as you need
    border: 3px solid #000;
}

#imgToShow .imgZoomClass
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
```

For more detail you can check fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rm1sxo3u/

Comment: Thanks, but i need the Images to "fade into each other" so there will be NO loading or flickering effects in browsers

Comment: Then I think you need to do something CSS.. let me try to do

Comment: Hm, now the new Image disappears after loading

Comment: I am modifying answer

Comment: Yeah man that looks very nice! I will test it in my whole application.

Comment: But the "trick" here is the fadeIn  delay of 1 sec. So if the Image is bigger this 1 sec isn't enough. To keep it flexible a solution which works with "load" or something else would be better.

Answer (score 0):

You should attach an `onLoad` handler to the image and trigger the removal/fade out of the previous image from there. Something like:

```
$(".imgZoomClass:last").on('load', function() {
    $(".imgZoomClass:first").remove().fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: Can you describe "flickering" a bit more specifically?

Comment: The area where the Image shall be shown was first black and the Image is loading slowly, then the Image is shown. Something like this...
The Images must fade into each other so there will be no effects anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing your logic in `success`, you can write in `jQuery`'s [complete](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax).

> **complete**
>   *Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus )*
>
> A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and
>   error callbacks are executed).